# After motherboard replacement on Dell XPS 13, hard drive is not accessible

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, dell

I have (well, had) a dual boot setup on a Dell XPS 13, with windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.       The motherboard died and was replaced by Dell.  As always, this hosed my grub setup.    I proceeded in the usual way, to boot to ubuntu from a usb drive, and then tried to mount my linux partitions,  but now my hard-drive is not visible.

I wonder if the source of my problem was that the windows partition on my original drive was somehow hosed.    I could not get to it from my grub menu before the motherboard replacement. And after the replacement, I couldn't get to windows 10 either.    I *could* get to a dos prompt, telling me that windows is still there in some form, but I could not get windows to repair itself.

Here's the output of the usual commands, run from the `try ubuntu` screen:

from:    `sudo fdisk -l`   (all I'm seeing is /dev/sda, which is the usb drive)

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.7 GiB, 1831378944 bytes, 3576912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 28.9 GiB, 31004295168 bytes, 60555264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2b192737

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          0 3753599 3753600  1.8G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       3672780 3677451    4672  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

From `lshw -class storage -class disk`

```
 *-storage
       description: RAID bus controller
       product: 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 17
       bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage msix pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:dc2a0000-dc2a7fff memory:dc2b9000-dc2b90ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:dc200000-dc27ffff
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1.1
       logical name: scsi8
       capabilities: emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
     *-disk
          description: SCSI Disk
          product: DT microDuo 3.0
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@8:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          logical name: /cdrom
          version: PMAP
          serial: 4B018AD15FC9
          size: 28GiB (31GB)
          capabilities: removable
          configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048 sectorsize=512 state=mounted
        *-medium
             physical id: 0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             logical name: /cdrom
             size: 28GiB (31GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048 signature=2b192737 state=mounted
```

Similarly, `gparted` shows only the usb drive, the hard drive is absent.

In desperation I tried to reinstall ubuntu, but couldn't even do that:  the only drive that was visible was the usb drive /dev/sda.

Any help would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: If it's a partition issue like you think then boot into ubuntu live, open gparted and delete all the partitions, including windows because who needs it anyway. don't forget to create a gpt/efi if you have uefi boot.

Comment: @beertempest, my hard drive doesn't even show up on gparted!   It's 100% awol

Comment: Check SATA and power cable connectors of the harddrive.

Comment: Have you changed the SATA setting from RAID to AHCI in the BIOS yet?

Comment: Then you might want to check the mainboard again and/or test the hard drive in another machine to see if it's pooched. At the very least check the connections

Comment: Thanks a million @Steve, that's all it took, chaning the BIOS setting as you suggested.      Could you please convert your comment to an answer, please, so that I can accept it?     After the change, Windows fixed itself, and I could rebuild grub.    The total mystery is:   how come nobody at Dell thought to try this???     If it were just a linux problem I could understand, but the RAID setting prevented *Windows* from repairing itself.    They are supposed to know about Windows.